# script5009: 'Primefaces' is undefined in IE9 - Error disappears after reloading

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces

I'm extremely disappointed. I'm still searching for a reason of a bug, that i got after changing the template layout of my page. I'm using Primefaces 3.4.2 with Tomcat 7.0.32 and JSF 2.1.13 Library.

*What does this bug?:*

**In Opera, FF and Chrome:**

All elements are fully loaded and displayed.

But if you select or invoke a menuitem (defined non-ajax) the page gets reloaded, as expected. But nothing happens. If you invoke the button a secound time, it gets invoked. And the content section is changed.

If you select and row of an datatable or something like that, the page is working very smooth. And you need no second try to change the content section.

**In IE6+ especially IE9:**

The page is loaded and the IE9 displays, in the most cases, all elements. But there are no hovers or ajax events you can invoke. The page seems to be frozen.

Do you reload the page, it works as expected. Fast and smooth.

**What i did to debug**

I started to find the reason for it. I looked in the console of each browser. The non IE browsers give no hint for an reason. In the most cases there are no errors in this direction.

The IE says the following errors if you start a fresh session and you are loading the page for the first time.

[image: IE CONSOLE]

After reloading the errors disappear.

The tomcat gives no exception, too.

**What i did to my layout:**

I create a custom theme with the JQuery ThemeRoller and implemented it as link.
Note: The Bug is still there if you are using the default theme

I decided to remove a `<p:menu>` on the left side and move it into the header.
Note: I change all to default, the bug is still there.

I removed all `<p:panelgrid>` elemtents and switch it to simple `<table>`s
Note: But i think not that this was the reason for the bug.

I need to add and fix for an known issue with the z-index in IE browsers. You can see it in the script section of the `layout.xhtml` - without it the menubar is in the background of the elements in the content section.
Note: I removed it and nothing happens, the bug is still there.

And i deleted all caches. But nothing. I hope someone can help me or find the mistake i did.

**[SOURCE FILES]**

*My template layout file = `layout.xhtml`*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
    <f:view contentType="text/html">
        <h:head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
            <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval};url=#{request.contextPath}" />
            <f:event listener="#{loginController.verifyUseLogin()}" type="preRenderView" />

            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/faces/resources/primefaces-fes/theme.css"/>
            <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="#{request.contextPath}/faces/resources/css/app.css"/>


            <title>Willkommen im FLOW / Fast Lean Overhead Workflow - Dies ist ein PROTOTYP</title>
            <script type="text/javascript">

                PrimeFaces.locales['de'] = {
                    closeText: 'Schließen',
                    prevText: 'Zurück',
                    nextText: 'Weiter',
                    monthNames: ['Januar', 'Februar', 'März', 'April', 'Mai', 'Juni', 'Juli', 'August', 'September', 'Oktober', 'November', 'Dezember'],
                    monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mär', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Okt', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
                    dayNames: ['Sonntag', 'Montag', 'Dienstag', 'Mittwoch', 'Donnerstag', 'Freitag', 'Samstag'],
                    dayNamesShort: ['Son', 'Mon', 'Die', 'Mit', 'Don', 'Fre', 'Sam'],
                    dayNamesMin: ['S', 'M', 'D', 'M ', 'D', 'F ', 'S'],
                    weekHeader: 'Woche',
                    firstDay: 1,
                    isRTL: false,
                    showMonthAfterYear: false,
                    yearSuffix: '',
                    timeOnlyTitle: 'Nur Zeit',
                    timeText: 'Zeit',
                    hourText: 'Stunde',
                    minuteText: 'Minute',
                    secondText: 'Sekunde',
                    currentText: 'Aktuelles Datum',
                    ampm: false,
                    month: 'Monat',
                    week: 'Woche',
                    day: 'Tag',
                    allDayText: 'Ganzer Tag'
                };

                //needed to get the Submenu in menubar to the front (z-index bug)
                $(function() {
                        var zIndexNumber = 1000;
                        // Put your target element(s) in the selector below!
                        $("div").each(function() {
                                $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
                                zIndexNumber -= 10;
                        });
                 });

            </script>            
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
            <div id="outerWrapper">

                <table id="contentWrapper">
                    <tr>
                        <td id ="header">
                            <ui:insert name="header"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td id="content">
                        <ui:insert name="content"/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

*The `app.xhtml`*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<ui:composition template="./layout/layout.xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:define name="header">
        <ui:include src="./misc/menuheader.xhtml"/>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <ui:include src="#{appController.content}.xhtml" />
    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

*the navigation method from `@ManagedBean - @SessionScoped` Bean:*

```
public void doNav(){

    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    String selectedPageViewId =
    context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("pageViewID");

    if (selectedPageViewId.equalsIgnoreCase("page1"))
    {
    content = "/app/includes/hldyplanning";
    message = "Urlaub eintragen";
    ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext();
    hplC = (HldyPlanningController) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication()
                    .getELResolver().getValue(elContext, null, "hldyPlanningController");
    hplC.init();
    }
    else if (selectedPageViewId.equalsIgnoreCase("page2"))
    {
    message = "persönliche Übersicht";
    content = "/app/includes/persview";
    } [...]        
    else { context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Seite nicht gefunden.", "Wie sind Sie hier hingekommen?")); }
}

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

    <h:form id="frm_plan">
        <p:messages id="messages" autoUpdate="false" closable="true"/>
        [...]
    </h:form>
</html>
```

*The header:*

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:form id="frm_menu">
        <table class="steamlessBody" style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="header_boxes" style="width: 200px;">
                    #{appController.message}
                </td>
                <td class="header_boxes" style="width: 650px;">
                    <p:menubar autoDisplay="true" style="font-size: 14px; border: none; background: none;">
                        <p:submenu id="sub1" icon="ui-icon-calendar" label="Urlaubsplanung">
                            <p:menuitem id="btn_page1" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-plusthick" value="Urlaub eintragen" action="#{appController.doNav()}">
                                <f:param id="pageHLDYPLANNING" name="pageViewID" value="page1"/>
                            </p:menuitem>
                            [...]
                        </p:submenu>
                        [...]
                        <p:menuitem id="btn_logout" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-circle-close" value="Ausloggen" action="#{appController.logout()}"/>
                    </p:menubar>
                </td>
                <td class="head_text">
                    Eingeloggt als #{loginController.sessionData.user_name}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p:dialog widgetVar="help" id="dlg_help" closable="true" header="Hilfe" modal="true" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">

        </p:dialog>
    </h:form>
</html>
```

Comment: I am getting the same errors (at p:commandButton), were you able to find a solution?

Comment: ah the below answer fixed it for me. I didn't try it out at first as it was not accepted as answer by the OP. It works :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar issue today. The problem turned out to be the link to the page that had the issues.

I had code similar to this:

```
<p:commandLink action="badPage.jsf" id="btnBadPage" 
    value="Bad Page" actionListener="#{myBean.someAction}" />
```

When I changed the action URL as follows, I stopped receiving the javascript errors in IE:

```
<p:commandLink action="badPage.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" id="btnBadPage" 
    value="Bad Page" actionListener="#{myBean.someAction}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wrap any problematic components that don't work in a `<div>` tag, and often, these types of errors go away (when they do occur).

For example, I had an issue with paging in a `<p:dataTable>` that didn't work until I wrapped it in a `<div>`.  After that, it worked.

Anyway, it's something else for people to try.